# How to transform an array into multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have an array like:

```
Array
{
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
    [three] => 3
    [four] => 4
    ...
}
```

but I need to transfer this into a multidimensional array like that:

```
Array
{
    [one] => Array
        {
            [two] => Array
                {
                    [three] => Array
                        {
                            [four] => Array
                                {
                                ...
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: and where their values will go?

Comment: A loop might work. What have you tried?

Comment: @Drakula I don't realy need values. Keys are important.